# How can I Define Visible Columns in a PickList, in zappdev

Tags: zappdev

Inside my form, I have a picklist. But when I validate I get this type of error:
"No visible Columns defined". Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After selecting the picklist, on the right side of the screen you can see its properties. There is a button called Column Options... you can select your visible columns from there.

https://www.screencast.com/t/QBar3gZk

Careful, if you have changed properties of the dataset model you might need to refresh your form before you can see the changes .

Comment: Thank you that's what I wanted. Also the advise for the refresh of the form was very useful.